# Generating java classes from wsdl

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, wsdl, cxf

I have an wsdl, from it i generated server stubs using apache cxf. The problem is new wsdl which i deploy differs from initial one, so soap requests for old one do not work for the new one. I test it using soapUI. New ones have this weird namespace **init**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:init="http://initiator.clientprovisioning_1_0.mdm.smarttrust.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <init:cpDiscovery.Response>
```

Old soap messages didnt had this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cpDiscovery.Response>
```

I'll provide whatever additional info is needed. I've been trying to solve this for 2 days now. Please help.

**EDIT**
this **init** prefix depends on first letters the java package. So for example if classes are in me.mycompany.example prefix is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:exam="http://example.mycompany.net/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <exam:cpDiscovery.Response>
```

**EDIT**
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html#DevelopingaService-AnnotatingtheCode
this states

> targetNamespace property Specifies the target namespace under which the service is defined. If this property is not specified, the target namespace is derived from the package name.

how do i get rid of this?

Comment: Has the WSDL changed since the original code was generated?

Comment: Is there any way you could revert back to the old WSDL? Is your WSDL auto generated by some framework on the server? If so, try using the same framework to generate your client.

Comment: No its on my local disk. I meessed something during code generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "old" soap message is actually invalid and likely should have never worked.   Per the soap spec, children of the soap:Body MUST be namespace qualified.  It looks like the "new" behavior is the one you want.

Comment: I want old behavior. Is there a way to remove prefix?

Comment: Cxf seem to have these thingies - interceptors and transformation. Can can i just use those to add prefixes to "old soap messages" on the fly?

Comment: You can use the transformation feature: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transformationfeature.html  to qualify the element.  An inTransformElements map of cpDiscovery.Response -> {http://initiator.clientprovisioning_1_0.mdm.smarttrust.com/}cpDiscovery.Response  should do it

Comment: Thank you so much, Daniel. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

You've introduced a namespace into the XML schema that describes your SOAP payload.  This shouldn't affect a client's ability to invoke your service, as long as they can access the schema file.

Comment: Thanks for response. How do i fix this issue?